# Stripe loader doesn't disappear after the form closing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

I've implemented Stripe payment system, and it works fine. My problem is when I close opened stripe form, stripe loader doesn't disappear, and it doesn't allow me to do any action on the view until I reload the web page.

I open stripe form using the following code from `Stripe` documentation

```
StripeCheckout.open({
        key: key.getAttribute('value'),
        amount: amountInCents,
        name: 'AUGmentecture',
        image: '../images/icon/AUGmentecture_faviconpng.png',
        //iconColor: '#666EE8',
        color: '#31325F',
        description: 'Subscription for ' + planName + ' (' + billedType + ')',
        panelLabel: 'Subscribe',
        token: token,
        email: key.getAttribute('name'),//'@User.Identity.Name',
        allowRememberMe: false
    });
```

I've attached a picture showing the situation I have. The picture is made after closing `Stripe` form.
[image]

How to hide the loader?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I don't have any error, but I have a warning about `http`, can that cause a problem?